# Using a Javascript Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7.
In app.js I have these codes to specify routes.

```
var app = new Framework7({
  root: '#app',
  theme: 'ios',
  tapHold: true,
  view: {
    stackPages: true,
  },
  // Create routes for all pages
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      url: 'index.html',
    },
    {
      path: '/single/',
      url: 'pages/post.php?id=',
    }
  ]
});
```

And I have this data

```
var getId = "";    
$(".yaziaclass").click(function() {
        var getId = this.id;

    });
```

I want to use this data in route configuration.

```
url: 'pages/post.php?id='+getId
```

The problem is it doesn't see the id. I guess it's because of the click action.
I want to change the getId's value when an user click a post. And use it in route configuration codes.
How can I fix it?

Comment: you are defining the variable in the scope of the click function. Nothing outside can access it. You need to define it in a more global/shared scope

Comment: @sinanspd I defined it like `var getId = ""` and it works. But I want to use the post id which a user clicked. How can I define it?

Comment: Javascript has lexical scope. The ```var``` keyword will ***redefine*** a variable in the current scope. Meaning ```var getId = this.id;``` won't change the previous getId but define a new one. Try ```getId = this.id;``` Also note ```this``` inside the function will be defined by the function call. I am not confident if it will work since I don't have the full picture

Comment: @sinanspd I tried your suggestion not using **var**. When I alert getId, it gives me the correct id. But still nothing outside can access it... It doesn't change...

Comment: @sinanspd Hocam Türk'sün sanırım. Tıkandım kaldım bir yardım et bana:)

Comment: I am Turkish but SO is strictly English so let's try to stick to the language we all agreed on :) I have never used Framework7 however from a quick look, I think another problem is that once your app object is initialized there is no way of changing it. So that object will not pick up the changes in the variable even if you can append the variable to the URL. Based on the documentation the proper way of doing this would be ```{path: '/single/:id,  url: 'pages/post.php?id={{id}}'```, than you can navigate to the correct path on click rather than mutating (mutation is bad anyway)

Comment: Docs: https://framework7.io/docs/routes.html

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the function written above to ES6.

```
let getId = "";    
$(".yaziaclass").click(() => {
        getId = this.id;
});

console.log(getId);
```

If you don't want to use ES6, then use the following:

```
var getId = ""; 
function handleClick(){
  getId = this.id
}   
$(".yaziaclass").click(handleClick.bind(this));

console.log(getId); // should have updated the global `getId` value
```

I would also suggest you to read about Global and Local scopes in Javascript.